# Value counts for every field of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgresSQL, I am trying to get the value counts of every field and value pair.  For illustration, I have 2 columns, but I really have 100 columns.  So, I need a programmatic solution.

For a table,

```
| id | name  | gender |
-----------------------
| 1  | john  | male   |
| 2  | susan | female |
| 3  | john  | male   |
| 4  | john  | male   |
| 5  | susan | female |
| 6  | john  | male   |
| 7  | susan | female |
| 8  | julie | female |
| 9  | julie | female |
```

I know that

```
select name, count(*) as value_count
from table_name
group by name
```

gives me what I want for one column:

```
| name  | value_count |
-----------------------
| john  | 4           |
| susan | 3           |
| julie | 2           |
```

But how can I programmatically iterate through all the columns and generate this, for example:

```
| column_name | value_name | value_count |
------------------------------------------
| name        | john       | 4           |
| name        | susan      | 3           |
| name        | julie      | 2           |
| gender      | male       | 4           |
| gender      | female     | 5           |
```

Comment: looks like you need a `cursor`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, thanks for the tip. do you mind showing me?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, I am accessing through Python if that simplifies things.

Comment: well, but I don't know about the syntax of plpgsql unfortunately, but I suppose `cursor` should be used within that also.

Comment: Sample table data giving that result would help a lot.

Comment: @jarlh, added sample data

Comment: In SQL Server I would probably create a dynamic SQL using information_schema.columns. I'm guessing PostgreSql has it's own syntax for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`grouping sets`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS):

```
select name, gender, count(*) as value_count
from my_table
group by grouping sets ((name), (gender))

 name  | gender | value_count 
-------+--------+-------------
 john  |        |           4
 julie |        |           2
 susan |        |           3
       | female |           5
       | male   |           4
(5 rows)
```

If you are determined to get the result in the mentioned format:

```
select 
    case when gender is null then 'name' else 'gender' end as column_name,
    coalesce(gender, name) as value_name,
    value_count
from (
    select name, gender, count(*) as value_count
    from my_table
    group by grouping sets ((name), (gender))
    ) s

 column_name | value_name | value_count 
-------------+------------+-------------
 name        | john       |           4
 name        | julie      |           2
 name        | susan      |           3
 gender      | female     |           5
 gender      | male       |           4
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a union on these

```
select 'name' as column_name, name as value_name, count(distinct id) as value_count
from table_name
group by name
union
select 'gender' as column_name, gender as value_name, count(distinct id) as value_count
from table_name
group by gender
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do what you want if the values are compatible (i.e. all strings), so let me assume that is the case.

Then, you can use a lateral join:

```
select col, val, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('name', name::text),
             ('gender', gender::text),
             . . .
     ) v(col, val)
group by col, val
order by col, count(*) desc;
```

You need to fill in the `values()` statement.  Actually, you can generate the code using a `select` statement on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.